# Why is the second column of my data.frame not printing

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I need help with my second column. It is not printing. My program is looping through giving me the correct hospitals but is not giving me my second column the statelist. (the state abbreviation where the hospital is located)

This is what I get:

```
[1] "ALASKA REGIONAL HOSPITAL"
[1] "BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER EAST"
[1] "BAPTIST HEALTH MEDICAL CENTER NORTH LITTLE ROCK"
[1] "CARONDELET HEART AND VASCULAR INSTITUTE"
[1] "OLYMPIA MEDICAL CENTER"
```

but this is what I need

```
[1] "ALASKA REGIONAL HOSPITAL"                           "AK"                                                 
[1] "BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER EAST"                        "AL"
[1] "BAPTIST HEALTH MEDICAL CENTER NORTH LITTLE ROCK"    "AR"
```

Here's the code

```
states<-unique(dat$State)
state<-(sort(states))
for (i in 1:length(state))
    statelist<-state[i]
    HospitalName<-data.frame()
    for(i in 1:length(state)) {
        if(outcome=="heart attack" && num==num) {
            sub.heart.attack <- subset(dat,State==state[i],select=c (Hospital.Name,Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack))
            order.heart.attack <- order(as.numeric(sub.heart.attack[,2],na.rm=TRUE))
            number1.heart.attack <- order.heart.attack[num]
            HospitalName <- print(sub.heart.attack$Hospital.Name[number1.heart.attack])
            statelist
        }
    }
    HospitalName<-data.frame(HospitalName,statelist)
}
```

Comment: The only thing you are printing is `print(sub.heart.attack$Hospital.Name[number1.heart.attack])` and that doesn't include the state at all so I hope it's not a surprise that the state isn't printing

Comment: I thought that HospitalName<-data.frame(HospitalName,statelist) would print out the HospitalName and statelist. When I didn't put the print in front of HospitalName<-print my loop values did return.

Comment: I changed the last 3 lines of code                                                                    HospitalName<-print(sub.heart.attack$Hospital.Name[number1.heart.attack])
print(state[i])
}}
{
HospitalName<-data.frame(HospitalName=HospitalName,state=state)
 
}                                                                    my output is: The state is listed under the Hospital                                                                   [1] "ALASKA NATIVE MEDICAL CENTER"
   [1] "AK"
   [1] "GEORGIANA HOSPITAL"
   [1] "AL"
but I need my code to be "Alaska Native Medical Center" "AK"

Comment: Consider adding the first 10 rows of your original data set before subsetting any columns.  Also, if you edit your code consider doing so in the original post rather than in the comments.

Comment: In other words, you are far more likely to get a useful answer if people can copy your code and your example data from this site and paste it into their computer and have the code run and initially return the same result that you are getting.

Comment: Output of a `dput(dat)` or `dput(heat(dat, 30))` would greatly help folks help you.